# How to retreive a field from JSON string stored in database

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following string

```
[{"id":"select","component":"select","editable":true,"index":2,
  "label":"WHAT IS THIS QUESTION?","description":"some description",
  "placeholder":"placeholder","options":["Aligator","Pikachi"],"required":false,
  "validation":".*","$$hashKey":"object:38"}]
```

stored in the database.

I want to retrieve the `validation` value. How can I achieve this using LINQ? I am using EF Core 2 and I am unable to get ahead in my query.

```
var jsonData = from table in myRepository.Table
               where table.JSONString.........
```

`JSONString` is the name of the column which stores the JSONString.

I have been searching posts on SO and on google for a while but have not found an answer yet. Thanks.

Updates:

I created classes for the JSON like the following

```
public class FormJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "component")]
    public string component { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

but I still dont have a clue on how I can map this specific class to my JSON Object and get the field I need.

Comment: There are numerous ways of parsing JSON. Have you tried the answers to [How can I parse JSON with C#?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6620165)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the NuGet-package `Newtonsoft.Json` to include `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Fetch the JSON-string from your database:

```
var jsonStr = (from t in myRepository.Table select t.JSONString).FirstOrDefault();
```

Parse the JSON-string to `JObject`:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
```

Read the value of a specific token you want to access:

```
JToken validation = json.GetValue("validation");
```

Do something with the value:

```
string value = validation.ToString();
JToken[] valueArray = validation.ToArray();
```

**Edit:**

As there is something wrong with `JObject.Parse()` whilst using your JSON (which is valid), instead of using `JObject.Parse()`, try the following:

```
// Add references for TextReader and JsonReader
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

TextReader tReader = new StringReader(jsonStr);
JsonReader jReader = new JsonTextReader(tReader);
JObject json = JObject.Load(jReader);
JToken validation = json.GetValue("validation");
```

Comment: oRole, I have tried that approach but I run into problems like `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 217.'`

To fix the error above I have tried multiple things. Any things you can suggest to fix that?

Comment: Sounds like the JSON-string you used is not a valid one. Parsing will only work if the JSON-string is valid. Try to insert and validate your JSON here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. I tried it with the string you have posted and it should work now.

Comment: I highly appreciate you taking time and trying to help me but unfortunately that did not work either. I am very confused myself on why I cant parse the data correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176917/discussion-between-maddy-and-orole).